# Set number of workers for each task in schedule

Tags: celery

I have 4 scheduled task in Celery which executes every N seconds. 
Now, application logic provides only one worker for each task ( it write-reads data from db, and parallel execution are not allowed).

But I can set only 1 worker for all tasks by using 
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1

How can I set single worker for each task? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you don't want your 4 tasks to run in parallel? If that is the case you should use something like a 'Chain' of subtasks, see:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains

Just add your tasks to a chain with the | operator, and then execute it with delay() or async_delay(). In that way, your next task will only start after the previous one has completed. And one worker from the pool will be assigned to each task (which can be the same worker or a different one).